# Getting error Operator '!=' cannot be applied to 'Boolean' and 'Int' in a very simple if statement

Tags: android, kotlin

Here is a part of my code in Kotlin:

```
if (result[0] != 0 and result[2] != 0){
            textView_result.text = result[2].toString() + " " + result[0].toString() + "/" + result[1].toString()
        }
```

To clarify, result is a List with length 3. This is a very simple code that if the number at index 0 and 2, both are not equal to zero, then the following has to be run.

However, in the condition specified for if, I'm getting this error:

> Operator '!=' cannot be applied to 'Boolean' and 'Int'

Am I doing something wrong?

Edit: I tried making new Integer values for result[0], [1] and [2] and replacing them with the integer, but to no avail.

Comment: check out this doc https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/equality.html

Comment: you can cast the value that is getting interpreted as a bool to an int.

Comment: `and` is bitwise operator similar to `&` in java or many other languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use && instead of **and**

```
if (result[0] != 0 && result[2] != 0){
        textView_result.text = result[2].toString() + " " + result[0].toString() + "/" + result[1].toString()
    }
```

Because **and** operator required both side Integer(someInt **and** someInt)  But in your case result[0] != 0 and result[2] != 0 both evaluates to boolean values then **and** operator is applied which is not permitted

Other way you can cast values and use **and** operator

Answer (score 1):

Make Another int called
List1 = result[1];
Like that, then try to replace it in the condition instead of result[x]